# Javascript - undesired alert box behavior

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple form on a website that contains two radio buttons, and I have added some Javascript form validation for when the neither of the radio buttons are clicked. (thanks SO)  However when the user clicks the okay button the page is redirected to the "process" page for the form.  I would prefer the behavior of just reloading the page or closing the alert box when the user clicks the "ok" button in the alert box.

To further see what I'm talking about you can go to chrisrjones.com which should redirect you to chrisrjones.com/splash.php then click enter. (without selecting a radio button) An alert box should appear, and once the *okay* button is pressed, the page redirects to the form process page (not what I want).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>chrisRjones.com - Splash</title>

 <?php
function getImagesFromDir($path) {
    $images = array();
    if ( $img_dir = @opendir($path) ) {
        while ( false !== ($img_file = readdir($img_dir)) ) {
            // checks for gif, jpg, png
            if ( preg_match("/(\.gif|\.jpg|\.png)$/", $img_file) ) {
                $images[] = $img_file;
            }
        }
        closedir($img_dir);
    }
    return $images;
}

function getRandomFromArray($ar) {
    mt_srand( (double)microtime() * 1000000 ); // php 4.2+ not needed
    $num = array_rand($ar);
    return $ar[$num];
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is the only portion of the code you may need to change.
// Indicate the location of your images 

$root = '';
// use if specifying path from root
//$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path = 'pics/';

// End of user modified section 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Obtain list of images from directory 
$imgList = getImagesFromDir($root . $path);
$img = getRandomFromArray($imgList);
?> 





<!-- begin google analytics PHP include -->

<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

<!-- end google analytics PHP include -->

<!-- Javascript radiobutton form validation -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function valForm(form) {
    var btn1 = parseInt(form.splash.value, 10) || 0;
    btn = (btn1 )
    if (btn < 3) {
        alert('You either like splash pages or hate em, choose one ...please');
        return false; }
    else {
     alert('Button value ' + btn + ' selected');
    }
}
</script>

<!-- Javascript radiobutton form validation END -->


</head>

<body>
<img src="<?php echo $path . $img ?>" alt="" width="640" height="auto"  />
<h1>Hello Javascript redirection.</h1><br />
<p>

<form name="tosplashornottosplash" action="splash-process.php" method="post">
Splash pages are stupid 

<input type="radio" name="splash" value="false" /> No
<input type="radio" name="splash" value="true" /> Yes

<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" onClick="valForm(tosplashornottosplash)" value="Enter" />
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code will run exactly the same without an alert box - so start from there when looking at how to get the desired behavior. (A confirmation dialog has a result.)

Comment: @Chris you should try to include the relevant code in your question, especially when you basically say "the code I wrote doesn't work the way I want". People don't want to go digging through your site.

Comment: @AlexWayne He did provide the code (or at least a link to the page with the code embedded in the HTML). Though for future proofing he probably should paste it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return false from valform in situations you want to stay on the same page.

for example:

```
function valForm(form) {
var btn1 = parseInt(form.splash.value, 10) || 0;
btn = (btn1 )
if (btn < 3) {
   alert('You either like splash pages or hate em, choose one ...please');
   return false;
}
else {
     alert('Button value ' + btn + ' selected');
} 
}
```

You may also need to change your markup as follows adding the `return` statement.

```
<input type="submit" value="Enter" onclick="return valForm(tosplashornottosplash)" name="formSubmit">
```

Comment: bah, your code didn't work it gives an error, on the line with "else"

Comment: Was missing a bracket, try now.

Comment: think your still missing a bracket @ the end for the entire function

Comment: Yeah I am still getting redirected :-/

Comment: See my latest edit (including the markup change)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do a `return false` in there to prevent the default action.

```
function valForm(form) {
    var btn1 = parseInt(form.splash.value, 10) || 0;
    btn = (btn1 )
    if (btn < 3) { 
        alert('You either like splash pages or hate em, choose one ...please');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Button value ' + btn + ' selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: for whatever reaseon your code didn't work :-/  ...well I should say I used your code, but I'm still getting redirected

Comment: Define 'doesn't work' so I can help you.

Comment: @JohnFx I'm still getting redirected in Firefox 18

Comment: @Chris see my amended answer. You need to change your markup too.

Answer (score -1):

You could use JQuery.

```
function valForm(){
  if (!$("input[name=splash]:selected").length)
    alert('please select');
    return false;
  } else { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Yes he could certainly use jQuery, but that wasn't really asked about by the OP.  I actually would recommend him continuing to work with basic javascript until he gets down the basics (like `return false`). I think that will give him a much better basis to then be able to leverage the power of jQuery at some point.